Should I maintain a relationship between the periodic distance and the equilibrium distance?
I am performing a Monte Carlo (MC) simulation using the Lennard-Jones (LJ) potential.
Based on my understanding:

The length of the simulation box's edge, $L$, is defined as:
$$L = \left( \frac{N}{\rho} \right)^{\frac{1}{3}}$$
where:

$N$: Number of particles (or beads) in the system
$\rho$: Number density


$L$ also corresponds to the periodic distance, i.e., the maximum length before positions wrap around due to periodic boundary conditions.


Question:
In this scenario, should I maintain a relationship between the periodic distance and the LJ equilibrium distance $\sigma$?
